# RegEx: Extract GET variable from URL

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox-addon-sdk

RegExp gurus, heed my call!

This is probably super simple, but I've painted myself in a mental corner.

Taking a regular URL, split after the `?`, which gives a string like `variable=val&interesting=something&notinteresting=somethingelse` I want to extract the value of `interesting`.

The name of the variable I'm interested in can be a substring of another variable. 
So the match should be

- either beginning of string or "&" character
- followed by "interesting="
- followed by the string I want to capture
- followed by either another "&" or end of string

I tried something along the lines of
`[\^&]interesting=(.*)[&$]`
but I got nothing...

**Update**
This is to be run in a Firefox addon on every get request, meaning that jQuery is not available and if possible I would like to avoid the extra string manipulation caused by writing a function.

To me this feels like a generic "extract part of a string with regex" but maybe I'm wrong (RegEx clearly isn't my strong side)

Comment: Don't reinvent wheels, use a library: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri

Comment: Not made clear in the original question, but this is to be used inside a Firefox add-on (because I was really thinking there would be a pure RegEx solution), and due to various internal reasons I would really like to avoid writing a funciton to extract this for efficiency reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple solution

```
var arr = "variable=val&interesting=something&notinteresting=somethingelse".split("&");
for(i in arr) {
var splits = arr[i].split("=");
if(splits[0]=="interesting") alert(splits[1]);
}
```

also single line match

```
"variable=val&interesting=something&notinteresting=somethingelse".match(/(?:[&]|^)interesting=((?:[^&]|$)+)/)[1]
```

Comment: The single line match does not work if I change the order of `interesting` and `notinteresting` then it gives the value `somethingelse` instead of the desired `something`. But this is close to what I was looking for

Comment: edited regex :) it should work now

Comment: Excellent! Tested with the desired field in the beginning, middle, and end of the string and all works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getValue(query)
{
var obj=location.search.slice(1),
    array=obj.split('&'),
    len=array.length;
    for(var k=0;k<len;k++)
    {
        var elm=array[k].split('=');
        if(elm[0]==query)return elm[1];
    }

}
```

This function directly extract the query URL and return the corresponding value if present.

```
//usage
var get=getValue('interesting');
console.log(get);//something
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Add-on SDK for Firefox, you can use the url module:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/url.html

This is much better than using regex.